# In selenium webdriver,How to get a particular row and column content

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenium webdriver,How to get a particular row and column content.Like I need 2nd row 5th column element and my requirement keeps changing.Next I might need the 3rd row 1st column element.

Comment: Welcome to stack! Please post some `html` for the table you're wondering about as well as some **code** for what you've tried.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp   In this link we have a table.Now I am asking my user his preferred row and column number.He provides row number 2 and column number 3.System should print "Mexico".Again next time when I am running the same code,user provides row number 5 and column 2.Now system should print " Yoshi Tannamuri".Likewise my requirements keep changing.So how to create a method based on the input from user and then getting the cell content of the table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In `C#` Using a css selector:

```
IWebElement selection = WebDriver.FindElement(
             By.CssSelector("#customers tr:nth-of-type(" + rowNum + ") td:nth-of-type(" + colNum + ")"));
```

In `C#` Using an xpath:

```
IWebElement selection = WebDriver.FindElement(
             By.Xpath("//*[@id='customers']//tr[" + rowNum + "]//td[" + colNum + "]"));
```

Where `rowNum` and `colNum` are the row and column passed in.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be to use XPath. In Java this would somehow look like this:

```java
Integer row = 2;
Integer col = 3;
By by = By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']//tr[" + row.toString() + "]//td[" + col.toString + "]");
```